# ComboBoxes with current date in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date

Ok there is a pretty complicated thing I need done in Flash CS4 with as3. I've looked around the web but I couldn't find much useful info.

Basically I have 3 ComboBoxes, one for the UTC date, another for the UTC month and another for the UTC year. I need it to be done so that the comboboxes will show the dates inbetween a set date (a date which I initially set in the flash script) and the current UTC date. For example, if I put the set date as 1st of Feb 2013, and the current date is 4th of March, I want the user to only be able to select February and March in the 'month' combobox. If they select February, then the available dates in the 'date' combobox should be 1 - 28, but if March is selected then only 1 - 4 should be available. This should be able to update every day automatically, so for example on March 5th, the number 5 should be added so it should be 1 - 5 available on the 'date' combobox if March is selected and so on...

I honestly have no idea how to go about this, but I really need it done one way or another.  If anyone could help me I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a new month, your two boundary dates can update accordingly, then this function can help you generate the date in between

```
    private function test():void
    {
        var date1:Date = new Date(2012, 11, 25);
        var date2:Date = new Date();
        generateDateBetween(date1, date2);
    }

    private function generateDateBetween(date1:Date, date2:Date):void
    {
        for (var i:Number = date1.time; i < date2.time; i+= 3600*24*1000)
        {
            var date:Date = new Date();
            date.time = i;
            trace(date);
        }
    }
```